# Typing emoji in SMS limits number of characters to 70

Tags: sms, 4.2-jelly-bean, htc-one-x, emoticons

I have HTC One X running Android 4.2.2. While typing SMSs if I put an emoji character then it sets the maximum number of characters to 70. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because when you use emojis, you force the use of UTF-16 encoding instead of the regular 7 bit ASCII encoding. 7 bit ASCII encoding allows 160 characters per SMS, but since UTF-16 encoding takes up about twice as much data per character, it only allows 70 characters per SMS.